# Invoke-WebRequest in SQL Server Job

Tags: sql, powershell

I am trying to setup the following Powershell script within SQL Server Job. When running the script in powershell there is no issues, but when running from SQL Server Job Agent, it would not complete. It seems to be stuck running on $wr on the Invoke-WebRequest. Throwing this out there to see if anyone has a solution.

```
    [Void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Web");
    $dlUrl = 'PathtodownloadFile';
    $fileName = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlDecode((Split-Path -Path $dlUrl -Leaf));
    $dlPath = 'Path{0}'-f $fileName;
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $wr = Invoke-WebRequest 'LoginPageUrl' -SessionVariable ipc;
    $form = $wr.Forms[0];
    $form.Fields["username"] = $username; $form.Fields["password"] = $password;
    $wr = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ("PageURL" + $form.Action) -WebSession $ipc -Method POST -Body $form.Fields;
    Invoke-WebRequest -WebSession $ipc -Uri $dlUrl -OutFile $dlPath;
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Nope, I've tested it line by line as well. It'll get stuck here:
$wr = Invoke-WebRequest 'LoginPageUrl' -SessionVariable ipc;

Tried to output $wr it will not output the session either.

Comment: Did you test the `$ipc` session is valid?  Are you passing the `'LoginPageUrl'` as a variable and is it valid?

Comment: Running directly on Powershell it's all good. All URLs are valid and the $ipc var outputs:

Headers               : {}
Cookies               : System.Net.CookieContainer
UseDefaultCredentials : False
Credentials           : 
Certificates          : 
UserAgent             : Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT; Windows NT 6.2; en-US) WindowsPowerShell/4.0
Proxy                 : 
MaximumRedirection    : -1

Just doesn't work when I plug it into SQL Server Jobs.

Comment: Is SQL Server Jobs on a different host?  Does it have proper permissions?

Comment: SQL Server is on the same host. It has Admin on the server.
SQL Server is 2016

Right after this:
        $wr = Invoke-WebRequest 'LoginPageUrl' -SessionVariable ipc;
When I try to even output this by doing     $wr; the job will run indefinitely without completing or erroring out.

Comment: I have the same problem. Invoke-WebRequest is failing for SQL Agent but it runs standalone

Comment: see (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/onedrive/en-US/5c428f7b-f617-4103-b997-ea150dc186d9/using-powershell-invokerestmethod-in-job-step?forum=sqltools) for a workaround